# s3cmd no longer works correctly

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Without changing anything in the config or somewhere else, my s3cmd didn't work anymore. 
An `s3cmd la` or `s3cmd put` and `s3cmd get` works fine, but as soon as I want to create or delete a bucket I get the following error:

```
$ s3cmd mb s3://test

ERROR: S3 error: 403 (SignatureDoesNotMatch): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.
```

It is a s3 dynamic storage in the Swisscom Application Cloud.

Comment: s3cmd.ini: https://jsfiddle.net/rkw9st0o/

Comment: There are two thing you should check: 1. Ensure  that your time is synchronized. Usually a time offset is the cause of such errors.
2. please configure your s3cmd to use path-style access instead of virtual-host-style access.

Comment: Point 2 fixed the problem on my personal computer with s3cmd version 2.0.1, but it still doesn't work in the container with s3cmd version 1.0.0.

Comment: Since the CF Container is only Ubuntu Trusty, I can't install a newer version of s3cmd so I have to work with this old version and also a old config. .s3cfg in container: https://jsfiddle.net/ogkuu59m/

Comment: @seinol how did you install `s3cmd`? With apt buildpack? There is also minio client (GOLang)

Comment: Yes I installed it with the official cloudfoundry apt-buildpack. Okey I will try this other option.